# Extract data from Accordion in python using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation

I want to extract data from [Accordion](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example)

step:

1. go to the web site https://main.sci.gov.in/case-status#
2. fill random diary number, date and fill the captcha
3. You will get this screen

Question: I want to get data of **each Accordion**

First Accordion code -->

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='accordion']/div[2]/div[1]/h4/a").click()
```

[image]

Comment: What do you call `Accordion` at this page?

Comment: Accordion is nothing butToggle(https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example)